# How to customize the default service page in windows service using C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a sample Windows service. When executing the code it redirects to a default page that I set. But when I run it on the server it gives me a welcome page as attached screenshot

[image]

I tried setting a default page in `web.config` as follows :

```
<system.webServer>
     <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />               
                <add value="default.aspx"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
```

It is a basic html page with output >> Hello Service
But this does not get displayed when we hit the link

- URL/Service1.src

So is there a way I can customize  the page that is displayed.